# Make Browser.MsgBox if There Blank Cell in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Could you all help me? I want to make a project "Budget Monitoring" using Google Spreadsheet.
I'm already making the concept. There "Form" sheet for entering data. and then There "Data" Sheet as Database.
Form Sheet I'm using Script for Submit Data. I won't make, if there blank cell, there Browser.MsgBox to prevent the user to continue submitting data until the user fills the blank cell.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function submitData() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Data Sheet


  //Input Values

  var values = [[formSS.getRange("D5").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D7").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D9").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D15").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I15").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D17").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I17").getValue()]];

 datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 9).setValues(values);

  //Alert Msg
  var mftCell = formSS.getRange['D5','D7','D9','D13','I13','D15','I15','D17','I17'];
  if (mftCells="");
  Browser.msgBox('Enter Data  to Continue');

}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet with sample input data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is empty, you can use a for loop to check each value like this:

```
  //Input Values

  var values = [formSS.getRange("D5").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D7").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D9").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D15").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I15").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D17").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I17").getValue()];

 datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 9).setValues(values);

  //Alert Msg

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){

    if (values[i] == ""){ 

      Browser.msgBox('Enter Data to Continue');
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

> Remove the `break;` if you don't want to stop the loop when it finds
>   an empty cell.

You can also set `values` as a RangeList to improve the code:

```
var values = formSS.getRangeList(["D5","D7","D9","D13","I13","D15","I15","D17","I17"]).getRanges();
```

And as `values` is now an array of Ranges, change `values[i]` to `values[i].getValue()`:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){

    if (values[i].getValue() == ""){ 

      Browser.msgBox('Enter Data to Continue');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

More information about RangeLists [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)